# Proof of a lemma in Chevalley's Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $(E_i)_{i\in I}$ a family of $R$-modules.

> Let $\varphi$ be a multilinear mapping of $\prod_iE_i$ into a
> $R$-module $P$. For each $i$, let $(x_{ij})_{j\in J_i}$ be a family of
> elements of $E_i$ and $(\alpha_{ij})_{j\in J_i}$ a family of elements
> of $R$ such that $x_i:=\sum_{j\in J_i}\alpha_{ij}x_{ij}$ is defined
> (i.e. $\alpha_{ij}x_{ij}=0$ for almost all $j\in J_i$). Assume further
> that the following condition is satisfied: there exists a finite
> subset $I'$ of $I$ such that, whenever $i$ not in $I'$, $J_i=\{j_i\}$
> and $\alpha_{ij_i}=1$. Let $\Phi:=\prod_{i\in I}J_i$: then, for any
> $f\in\Phi$, the product $\prod_{i\in I}\alpha_{if(i)}$ is defined, the
> sum $$\sum_{f\in\Phi}\left(\prod_{i\in
>  I}\alpha_{i,f(i)}\right)\varphi((x_{if(i)})_{i\in I})$$ is defined and
> its value is $\varphi\left(\left(\sum_{j\in
>  J_i}\alpha_{ij}x_{ij}\right)_{i\in I}\right)$.

For each $i\in I$, let $J'_i:=\{j\in J_i\ |\ \alpha_{ij}x_{ij}\ne0\}$. On the other hand, write
$$\Lambda:=\left\{f\in\Phi\ | \prod_{i\in
 I}\alpha_{i,f(i)}\varphi((x_{if(i)})_{i\in I})\ne0\right\}.$$
Clearly $\Lambda\subset\prod_{i\in I}J'_i$. Note that $\prod_{i\in I}J'_i\simeq\prod_{i\in I'}J'_i\times\prod_{i\in I-I'}J'_i$. Obviously $\prod_{i\in I'}J'_i$ is finite. For each $i\in I-I'$ the set $J'_i$ has either $0$ or $1$ element; thus $\prod_{i\in I-I'}J'_i$ is finite. This implies that $\prod_{i\in I}J'_i$ is finite and so $\Lambda$ is finite: i.e. the family
$$\left(\left(\prod_{i\in
 I}\alpha_{i,f(i)}\right)\varphi((x_{if(i)})_{i\in I})\right)_{f\in\Phi}$$
has a finite support and so its sum is defined.

Now, Chevalley says that it is sufficient to prove the equality
$$\varphi\left(\left(\sum_{j\in
 J_i}\alpha_{ij}x_{ij}\right)_{i\in I}\right)=\sum_{f\in\Phi}\left(\prod_{i\in
 I}\alpha_{i,f(i)}\right)\varphi((x_{if(i)})_{i\in I})$$
for the case where $I$ is finite (by induction on the cardinality of $I$). Why would this be sufficient? Shouldn't the induction be done on the cardinality of $\Lambda$ instead of $I$?